# C# Java communication

Tags: c#, rpc, java

Здравствуйте! Есть приложение server-side написанное на C# и Android-приложение на Java. Каким образом можно организовать cвязь с возможностью RPC ? Возможно ли сделать duplex callback связь?
Хорошие статьи, примеры приветствуются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP (в частности REST) и протоколы, которые работают поверх HTTP (SOAP).

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону [CORBA](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA). Пример организации RPC между .NET и Java с использованием CORBA [здесь](http://javatutor.net/articles/java-and-dot-net-interaction-using-CORBA)

Comment: @Barmaley Боюсь бинарщина не очень подойдет для общения устройств с серверами в гетерогенной сети. Нельзя гарантировать, что нужные порты будут открыты. Да и насчет существования корбячих брокеров под Android я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Ну тогда только SOAP - ох не завидую я автору :)

Answer (score 1):

[RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Procedure_Call) работает как поверх HTTP так и независимо от него.
Обычно RPC текстовый: [JSON-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) или [XML-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC).

JSON-RPC отлично подойдет для взаимодействия C# и Android-приложение на Java - компактный и может быть реализован без сторонних библиотек.
При желании RPC можно и бинарным сделать, и использовать без HTTP и в дуплексном канале (например [WS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)).

А [SOAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) ИМХО, отживает свое - громоздкая, сложно поддерживаемая (без специализированных наворотов)... хм, штука.

Везде где используется SOAP его можно заменить JSON-RPC или XML-RPC (их можно немного расширить, если нужно подписывать сообщения).
А для описания веб-сервиса можно использовать компактное описание, например [SMD](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq2v3mgoTOAhVDDywKHWsCDOgQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdojotoolkit.org%2Freference-guide%2Fdojox%2Frpc%2Fsmd.html&usg=AFQjCNEUmaNwX2F204o-sq7N_KNDUnobaw&sig2=6c8Uzadrh12UPYq9XEGfUg).